# How to prove that $\frac{d}{dt}x(t)=-a x(t),\ x(0)=1,\ a>0$ will never go under 0?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, convergence-divergence, dynamical-systems

So let $\frac{d}{dt}x(t)=-a\times x(t),\ a>1$ and $x(0)=1$, is it possible to prove that $\lim_{t\to \infty} x(t)\geq0$ hence no matter how long $x(t)$ won't be lesser than 0. It ***seems*** that this statement to be true, as I've run a simulation (where $dt=10^{-7},\ a=72$) for more than 20 million frames and it seems to still be greater than 0. But still I can't think of a way to prove it mathematically. The most I could say is that because the lesser you are, the lesser you'll decrease, so you're not likely to get below 0.

Comment: The solution of this ODE is $x(t)=e^{-at}$.

Comment: A numerical computation is no good proof, especially if you don't vary $a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comments the solution of this ODE is $x(t)=e^{-at}$ as ${d\over dt}e^{-at}=-ae^{-at}$. So you need to prove that $\underset{t\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}e^{-at}=0$ if $a>0$.